# read a random subset of a csv file in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, dataset, machine-learning, svm

I have a large(150000) dataset in a csv format. the data set has some noise and error in some of the fields. I want to read this file and perform a classification with svm(with libsvm) on it.
I need to read a subset of the data which is clean and usable. Choosing 10000 random records that are clean and none of the fields are noisy. the fileds that are noisy has the value 0 or NA. How can I do this with matlab?

Comment: What about simply reading the entire file, dropping the noisy lines and then choosing from the remaining lines 10000 random lines?

Comment: I agree with @Eitan that it's the simplest solution. You'll have to either read the entire file or make a custom CSV parsing function which ignores rows with 0 or NA values while processing the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proper MATLAB solution, you will need to make a custom filereader. That's probably not worth the effort, though.

The fastest solution I can think of would be to filter out all erroneous lines using another tool (such as `grep`) prior to loading the file in MATLAB with `csvread`. If you have `grep`, you can get rid of lines with 'NA':

```
cat file | grep --invert-match NA > file.filtered
```

You can read file.filtered without issues with MATLAB's `csvread` function. You can get rid of rows with 0's from within MATLAB easily.